# Is it possible for a mod to provide a link to a question that I deleted more than 90 days ago?

Tags: support

I have a question that I've deleted that I need to refer back to for research purposes. It was not well received by the community, mostly because it couldn't be explained by current science. I have since found further evidence of this phenomena and would like to write a blog post on it.

I know deleted questions are kept for longer than 90 days so long as you have a direct link to them. Would it be possible for a mod to help me locate a cache of this post at the least? It's titled "Why am I a radio?"

Answer (score 4):

It wasn't posted from this account. However, there's [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/245078/11683) that was posted from one of your sock-puppet accounts.

Having multiple accounts is confusing at best, and deceptive/fraudulent in many cases. You should either [delete them](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) or have them [merged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Trust me. It's confusing for me too. And not on purpose. I'll look into having them merged. Thanks. I've undeleted the question and taken out stuff that is really dumb to look back on now. Let me know if my theory can be disproven if you can. Still makes no sense.